# Why $\mathbb R^2$ is defined by the cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I don't know whether this is a question at all but I would like to know why an element $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb R^2:=\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ corresponds exactly to the point $(x,y$) in the Cartesian coordinate system (as in coordinates determined by the ordered basis $\{i,j\}$).

This doesn't happen if we use polar coordinates, for example $(1,1)\in\mathbb R^2$ corresponds to $(\sqrt 2,\pi/4)$. What is the crucial property missing from other systems and how can I prove this?

Comment: In polar coordinates your example will only happen when you haven't restricted $\theta$.

Comment: Yes I assume polar coordinates in the form of $(r,\theta\mod 2\pi)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. There is only one basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to which each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ coincides with its coordinate vector, and that is the standard basis $(i,j)$. This is because any such basis $(e_1,e_2)$ satisfies $(x,y) = xe_1 + ye_2$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, and taking $x=1,y=0$ (respectively $x=0,y=1$) yields $i = e_1$ (respectively $j=e_2$).

Comment: Euclidean space actually started off without a coordinate description, only after the development of the Cartesian system did the relation reverse. So really $\mathbb{R}^2$ has no coordinates itself, when you put in place some coordinate system then you get the various expressions in Cartesian/polar/other such coordinate systems

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be the set of $n$-tuples of real numbers.

So there's a canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (seen as a vector space) given by $$e_1 = (1,0,0,...,0)$$ $$e_2 = (0,1,0,...,0)$$ $$\vdots$$ $$e_n = (0,0,0,...,1)$$ Now consider the dual basis $\{e^1,e^2,...,e^n\}$ s.t. $e^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j$.

The dual basis gives you natural coordinates $\{x^1,...,x^n\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $x^i(v):=e^i(v)$ for $i=1,2,...,n$ and $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then you can play with other systems of coordinates.

In the end, the canonical one is simply due to the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ are $n$-tuples of real numbers.